# Whisper: Error: failed to reach the PoW target, specified pow time (5 seconds) was insufficient

Tags: whisper

From [web3.py docs/SHH_API](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.shh.html#web3.shh.Shh.post):

> `ttl`: Time-to-live in seconds.
>   `powTime`: Maximal time in seconds to be spent on proof of work.
>   `powTarget`: Minimal PoW target required for this message.

On the following example I give one hour for the `ttl`. This could be much larger time such as 1 day and so on.

**[Q]** What is the benefit of using `powTarget` and `powTime`? How could I prevent the error I am having that is shown below?

When I increase `powTime`, the time required to sent the message also increases, so what could be the optimum `powTime` and `powTarget` for given seconds for the `ttl` (for example for one day)?

```
> web3.shh.post({
  pubKey: '0x04d96278caa49aff29d76399001a43a9a8005da21c6853d20d6af11d61df8a2a25de0fe79a1099bd4b915445d94cbd448b2fe548fb53fed5d887291f35de0f44c9',
  ttl: 3600,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 5,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });

Error: failed to reach the PoW target, specified pow time (5 seconds) was insufficient
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```